# How to make a function perform with a button input that was written for keyboard input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game for *iOS* and I have some pre-written code to perform an action within my game when the R key or any anywhere on the screen is clicked. I'm wanting this action to only be performed when I click/tap a designated button in game and not just anywhere on the screen.

I've tried changing one of the inputs to `Input.GetTouch()` and also adding the script to an existing button.

```
using UnityEngine;
using DiceMaster;

public class Roller : MonoBehaviour
{

    Spinner spinner;
    Thrower thrower;

    void Start()
    {
        spinner = GetComponent<Spinner>();
        thrower = GetComponent<Thrower>();

        if (spinner)
            spinner.autoDestroy = false;
        if (thrower)
            thrower.autoDestroy = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (thrower) thrower.Trigger();
            if (spinner) spinner.Trigger();
        }
    }
}
```

I want only the designated button in game to initiate the action (i.e tapping the button on an iPhone) but NOT when the screen is clicked anywhere else or if other buttons are pressed. What would be the best way to change it?

Comment: Put the code you want to run in a different public void method, and then place this method as reference to the OnClick event in the button from the unity inspector ui.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand as I'm new to this. I have 2 other scripts that give turning/gravitational properties to an object and with the script posted above when placed on the object gives them action. I'm familiar with the OnClick events in unity, but I don't know what you mean by putting the code I want to run (I'm presuming the 2 other scripts I mentioned) in a "different public void method". What would that look like?

Comment: take your code you want to trigger and put it in the OnClick-Event of your button. What Fragkos says is: `void Onclick(){ CodeToTriggerMethod();} void CodeToTriggerMethod(){ //Code}`. Your button should have a OnClickEvent, look up in the documentation